# Postgres CREATE EXTENSION All Databases

Tags: database, postgresql

I've got postgres installed in multiple environments.  In each of those environments, I have 2+ databases.

If I have superuser database rights, is there a way to install the CITEXT extension for all databases on a given postgres install?

As of right now, once logged into an environment and in a postgres console, I have to run `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext;` for each database.

Comment: you have to run it agaist each db separately. what you can do is writing a bash loop to run it against all dbs

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `CREATE` command does need to be run individually on each database, but you can easily automate this with a shell script, e.g.:

```
for DB in $(psql -t -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datname NOT IN ('postgres', 'template0', 'template1')"); do
  psql -d $DB -c "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext"
done
```

If you want `citext` to be included by default whenever you create a new database, you can also install the extension in [`template1`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html).

Comment: Good of you to include real example script example.

Comment: how to do the same thing without using `psql`?

Comment: @Madeo: It would be the same with any other client, i.e. connect to the `"postgres"` database, run the `SELECT datname` query to get a list of all other databases, then connect to each database in the list to run your `CREATE EXTENSION`.

Comment: @NickBarnes I am using the initdb script in Docker and I can only run `.sql` files.

Comment: @Madeo: If you can only run plain SQL scripts, then you can only create extensions in the database you're connected to. But the [docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) contain an example of an initdb `.sh` script which calls `psql`, so it looks like this should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
export PGPASSWORD='Xyz123';
for DB in $(psql -h localhost -U postgres -t -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datname NOT IN ('postgres', 'template0', 'template1')"); do

  psql -U postgres -d $DB -c "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_buffercache"
done

The script is only working for last database and for remaining dbs i am getting this error
**" **does not existAL:  database "debdbi123****. Please help on fixing the issue


++ psql -h localhost -U postgres -t -c 'SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datname NOT IN ('\''postgres'\'', '\''template0'\'', '\''template1'\'')'
+ for DB in $(psql -h localhost -U postgres -t -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datname NOT IN ('postgres', 'template0', 'template1')")
+ psql -U postgres -d $'debdbi123\r' -c 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_buffercache'
**" **does not existAL:  database "debdbi123****
+ for DB in $(psql -h localhost -U postgres -t -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datname NOT IN ('postgres', 'template0', 'template1')")
+ psql -U postgres -d 1 -c 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_buffercache'
NOTICE:  extension "pg_buffercache" already exists, skipping
--
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).